# How to detect if any native app is launched in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to develop an android app which launches only when we dial some specific number on dialer.

Here is the process:

1) **The app remains invisible by default (Both name and icon)**

2)  **When the user dials that specific number the app launches**

Basically the app is related to security.

Any idea or help on any of the above two issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register and implement a BroadcastReceiver to get the Intent of a outgoing call.
to intercept the intent an do your processing. You might need the PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html